# eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Compute the eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors of the following matrix T:

$$T =\begin{pmatrix} 1&4\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I have $(T-\lambda I)=0$ and from this I found $(\lambda -1)^2$, so $\lambda = 1$

But when I found eigenvectors, 
$\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&4\\ 0&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} X1\\ X2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ = $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

X2 = 0

X1 can take any value.

Using [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues%20%7B%7B1%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D)
I have two eigenvectors, (0,0) and (1,0) and the same eigenvalue λ=1.
What I'm doing wrong? Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: $(0,0)$ is by definition not an eigenvector (eigenvectors have to be nonzero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any triangular matrix the coefficients on the diagonal are the eigenvalues of the given matrix. In our case the only eigenvalue is $1$ and the vector $(1,0)^T$ is an eigenvector associated to $1$. There isn't other linearly independent eigenvector since the matrix isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: I'm a little confused, lets say that $\lambda=8$ and the matrix is triangular too, all the conditions are the same. Is $(8,0)^T$ the eigenvector of this new matrix?

Comment: For this matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&\alpha\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$
$\lambda$ is the unique eigenvalue and $(\beta,0)^T$ for all $\beta\ne0$ is an eigenvector  associated to this eigenvalue.

Comment: I'm agree with you. Then, why $(1,0)^T$ is the response, could have be any value instead 1?

Comment: Yes as I said $(\beta,0)^T$ is an eigenvector for all $\beta\ne0$; but notice that
$$(\beta,0)^T=\beta (1,0)^T$$
which means that $(1,0)^T$ *generates* all other eigenvectors

Answer (score 4):

As it ends up, this matrix has only the one eigenvalue ($\lambda = 1$) and the one dimensional eigenspace spanned by $\pmatrix{1&0}^T$.  The $0$-vector is *never* considered an eigenvector.

Note that it is, in a sense, unusual for an $n \times n$ matrix to have fewer than $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors (which is why WA looks for a $2$nd eigenvector where there is none). However, it is possible, as this problem exemplifies.  Matrices with fewer than $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors are **non-diagonalizable**.